# My EVEN ODD Program giving odd output for every 10 digit even number

Tags: c++, if-statement

I created odd even program to detect odd and even numbers. It is working fine for all numbers less than 10 digits but when I give input of 2222222222 in the code, it gives the output of odd but how?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a;
    cin>>a;

    if(a%2==0){
        cout<<"This is EVEN";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"This is ODD";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried giving input of 2222222222 and expected the output of even but it gave odd.

Comment: Why not read the number as a `std::string` and then just check the last digit?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using 32 Bit and thus, the integer ranges from 2 147 483 647 to -2 147 483 648. Use another datatype (e.g. `long long`) or switch to 64 Bit.

EDIT: As @wohlstad said in his comment, switching to 64 Bit might not solve the problem. Using another datatype is the way to go.

Comment: Is this code working fine on your system? (even with 10 digit numbers)

Comment: I didn't try it on my machine, but your code looks ok to me.

Comment: Using `long long` is a good idea to handle overflow assuming it is 64 bit. But the speculation about 32/64 bit system is not accurate. E.g. on Windows/MSVC `int` is 32 bit even in 64 bit builds.

Comment: switching to `std::string` and check last digit is a possibility.

Comment: Maybe the most performant solution can be achieved by using bitwise AND. Then something like `if (number_to_check & 1 == 0)` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **2222222222** is greater than the max value for `int` (i.e. **2147483647**). Thus it causes an overflow and it results in a wrong output.

There are a few ways to solve this problem. The easiest one is to use `long long` which has a large range (up to **9223372036854775807** in both 32 and 64 bit X86 variants).

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    long long int a;
    std::cout << "Enter a number in range "
              << 0
              << " to "
              << std::numeric_limits<decltype( a )>::max()
              << ": ";
    std::cin >> a;

    if ( a % 2 == 0 )
        std::cout << "This is EVEN\n";
    else
        std::cout << "This is ODD\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter a number in range 0 to 9223372036854775807: 2222222222
This is EVEN
```

Another way of doing it is to get the input as a `std::string` and then check to see whether or not its least significant digit is even.

This is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

bool is_number( const std::string_view str )
{
    const auto loc { std::cout.getloc() };

    for ( const char c : str )
        if ( !std::isdigit( c, loc ) ) return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number as big as you want: ";
        std::cin >> a;
    }
    while ( !is_number( a ) );

    if ( a.back() % 2 == 0 )
        std::cout << "This is EVEN\n";
    else
        std::cout << "This is ODD\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter a number as big as you want: 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222229
This is ODD
```

Now note that in the above solution, the condition `if ( a.back() % 2 == 0 )` may seem weird because `a.back()` returns a `char` and then we're applying the modulo (`%`) operator on it. This is valid since the ASCII values for even decimal digits are even as well (e.g. '0' == 48, '2' == 50, '4' == 52). So in the end, the result is guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: *"since the ASCII values for even decimal digits are even as well"*. How about EBCDIC? `(a.back() - '0' % 2) == 0` wouldn't rely of implementation specific stuff.

Comment: @Jarod42 Right.